# how to load a function when a page load react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using react-native with hooks, and I'm trying to load a JSON from AsyncStorage every time a user opens one of my react-native screens  This JSON contains information on what my states should be set to.

How can I call a function that runs every time this screen is opened?

i know that without hooks this should be done with useEffect, but when i put my api call there it makes an error

this is my code

```
useEffect(() => {
const getKind = () => {
    ForceApi.post(`/GetKindPensionController.php`)
      .then(res => {
        setpPensionKind(res.data.pension);
    })
  }


}, []);
```

Comment: What is the error? Also you are not calling the `getKind` method in the snippet above, so technically `useEffect` is not doing anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing call the getKind, and it should be a async function! For a better code try something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function getKind() {
       const { data } = await ForceApi.post(`/GetKindPensionController.php`)
       setpPensionKind(data.pension);
    }

    getKind();
}, []);
```